# I want to highlight cells that are not represented in table

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, matching

I Would like to highlight any cities in Column B that are not listed in Column C. I am having an issue where the conditional formatting function I am using =ISNA(MATCH(B2, $C$2:$C$100, 0)) is highlighting cities that are listed column C.

google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uFNw2NeCAehthkEHKsJfjDQVDBYmy-W5R-ZJ_b0eEOY/edit?usp=sharing

I tried two functions

=ISNA(MATCH(B2, $C$2:$C$100, 0))

=ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2, $C$2:$C$100, 1, FALSE))

Answer (score 0):

*You selected the range from `Cell_B1` while your formula setting started from `B2`; so the mismatch in the color highlighting of wrong cities. its fixed now & updated the formula to ignore blank cells as well*

```
=len(B2)*ISNA(MATCH(B2, $C$2:$C$100, 0))
```

[image]